# Get first value in CSV column without duplicates

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, csv, asp.net-web-api

I am getting a list of items from a csv file via a Web Api using this code:

```
private List<Item> items = new List<Item>();

        public ItemRepository()
        {
            string filename = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath + "App_Data\\items.csv";

            var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename).Skip(1).ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
            {
                var line = lines[i];

                var columns = line.Split('$');

                //get rid of newline characters in the middle of data lines
                while (columns.Length < 9)
                {
                    i += 1;
                    line = line.Replace("\n", " ") + lines[i];
                    columns = line.Split('$');
                }

                //Remove Starting and Trailing open quotes from fields
                columns = columns.Select(c => { if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(c) == false) { return c.Substring(1, c.Length - 2); } return string.Empty; }).ToArray();


                var temp = columns[5].Split('|', '>');
                items.Add(new Item()
                {
                    Id = int.Parse(columns[0]),
                    Name = temp[0],
                    Description = columns[2],

                    Photo = columns[7]



                });
            }
        }
```

The Name attribute of the item list must come from column whose structure is as follows:

`Groups>Subgroup>item`

Therefore I use `var temp = columns[5].Split('|', '>');` in my code to get the first element of the column before the ">", which in the above case is Groups. And this works fine.

However, I a getting many duplicates in the result. This is because other items in the column may be:

(These are some of the entries in my csv column 9)
`Groups>Subgroup2>item2`, `Groups>Subgroup3>item4`, `Groups>Subgroup4>item9`

All start with `Groups`, but I only want to get `Groups` once.

As it is I get a long list of `Groups`. How do I stop the duplicates?

I want that if an Item in the list is returned with the `Name` "Groups", that no other item with that name would be returned. How do I make this check and implement it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are successfully getting the list of groups, take that list of groups and use LINQ:

```
var undupedList = dupedList
    .Distinct();
```

Update: The reason distinct did not work is because your code is requesting not just Name, but also, Description, etc...If you only ask for Name, Distinct() will work.

Update 2: Try this:

```
//Check whether already exists
if((var match = items.Where(q=>q.Name == temp[0])).Count==0)
{
     items.add(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a List to store Item.Name?
Then check List.Contains() before calling items.Add()

Simple, only 3 lines of code, and it works.

```
IList<string> listNames = new List();
//
for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
{
    //
    var temp = columns[5].Split('|', '>');
    if (!listNames.Contains(temp[0]))
    {
        listNames.Add(temp[0]);
        items.Add(new Item() 
        { 
            //
        });
    }
}
```